# DAX Calculation With Multiple Parameters

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, formula

I am trying to calculate a daily net balance based on 4 fields.
1.) Balance from Previous Day
2.) Net Invoice Amount Current Day
3.) Payments on Current Day
4.) Adjustments Made Current Day.

In excel the logic is

Balance Prev Day plus Net Inv current minus Payment Current plus Adjustments Current.

I've created a measure that successfully calculates the Balance from the Previous day, but it only populates Day 1 of the month and won't fill any subsequent days until I can complete the formula successfully.

I also tried creating each part of the above formula as a measure.
I get very wrong numbers compared the excel sheet using the same data.

[image]

[image]

I am expecting to get a Balance per day that matches the excel sheet.
I tried calculating it as one complete measure, column, separate measures for the formula, but always get wrong outputs.

```
Day 1 balance = 1,018.2M
Day 10 Balance = 1,040.7M
Day 11 Balance = 1,043.5M
Day 12 Balance = 1,034.8M
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The main consideration in your case is making sure that each part of the calculation aggregates correctly and matches with the right day. Your measure should be like below :

```
Daily Net Balance = 
    [Balance Prev Day] 
    + SUM(NetInvoice[Net Invoice Amount]) 
    - SUM(Payments[Payment Amount]) 
    + SUM(Adjustments[Adjustment Amount])
```

and for the previous day calculation :

```
Balance Prev Day = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            ALL('YourTable'), 
            'YourTable'[Date] < MAX('YourTable'[Date])
        ),
        'YourTable'[Net Invoice Amount] 
        - 'YourTable'[Payment Amount] 
        + 'YourTable'[Adjustment Amount]
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Amira, 
Should the results be the so similar for both measures?

Comment: Can you please provide some data ? or your pbix file ?